# How to visualize data with chart.js properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chart.js

I am making a program, which get some data from an array and make another array. This another array needs to be visualize via chart.js in line chart, but something goes wrong there... This is my code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Visualize Data Beautifully Using JS Charts</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <form>
            <p>First value:</p>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="first">
            <br/>Last value:
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="secondname" id="second">
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </center>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#btnSubmit').on("click", function() {
                var array = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100];
                var newArray = [];
                var firstVal = $('#first').val();
                var lastVal = $('#second').val();

                for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    if (array[i] >= firstVal && array[i] <= lastVal) {
                        newArray.push(array[i]);
                    }
                }
                var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");

                for (var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
                    var data = {

                        labels: [1, 5, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],

                        datasets: [

                            {
                                fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                                strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                                pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                                data: newArray[i]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
                var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);
            });
        })
    </script>
    <div>
        <section>
            <article>
                <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400">
                </canvas>
            </article>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Can you please help me with that, because i have no idea where might be the mistake in the code, i am new with jquery and chart.js.

Answer (score 0):

Your button has `type="submit"`. This submits the form when you click it effectively refreshing it. Change it to `type="button"`

```
<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
```

The `data` property for a `dataset` should be an array. So you can take out the outer loop and directly plug in `newArray`

```
var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
var data = {
    labels: [1, 5, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    datasets: [
        {
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            data: newArray
        }
    ]
}
```

With these 2 changes, putting in a first and last value (say 20 and 60) will plot your chart.

However, **IF** you want the data to align with the original indices (and not be pushed to the left), you should be inserting null values in your first loop

```
if (array[i] >= firstVal && array[i] <= lastVal) {
    newArray.push(array[i]); // Add to new array
}
else {
    newArray.push(null);
}
```